# Strange characters in views when using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

When I debug my website in Visual Studio 2015, the html has strange characters (see screenshots below) in them. This breaks the rendering of my HTML.

When I work in Visual Studio 2012 however, it works correctly. I checked the encoding, it is a Signed UTF-8 file.

How can I fix this?

[image: console]

[image: source code]

Comment: I think you are returning Pdf. Show us the controller code

Comment: Well I don't think that's the case, I don't change the content type or return a stream. It really has to do something with VS 2012 and 2015.. Any thoughts?

Comment: is BrowserLink enabled in your Visual Studio 2015? http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/ (It is in the same place as in 2013 so link is valid)

Comment: I've disabled BrowserLink and it is working now. Thank you!